# How to show that whether $[ \frac{-p}{q}] =-[ \frac{p}{q}] $ or not?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to show that whether $[ \frac{-p}{q}] =-[ \frac{p}{q}]  $(1) or not?
I think it does not hold, because if p=3 and q=5, then by Euler criterion you get that $3^{\frac{5-1}{2}}= 3^2=9 \equiv 4 \equiv -1 \pmod 5$. So $-[ \frac{p}{q}]=-(-1)=1$. Now $[ \frac{-p}{q}]= [ \frac{-1}{q}][ \frac{p}{q}]= [ \frac{-1}{5}][ \frac{3}{5}]=1 \cdot (-1) = -1 \neq 1$. So it seems this (1) does not hold.
Can you prove that (1) does not hold?

Comment: You've provided a counter-example -- which is more than enough to prove the statement to be false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the "first supplement" to [quadratic reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity), $\left[\frac{-1}{q}\right]=(-1)^{\frac{q-1}{2}}$.  Hence $\left[\frac{-p}{q}\right]=\left[\frac{-1}{q}\right]\left[\frac{p}{q}\right]=-\left[\frac{p}{q}\right]$ exactly when $\left[\frac{-1}{q}\right]=-1$, which happens exactly when $q\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, assuming $p,q$ are odd primes.

Also, the notation $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)$ is preferred to  $\left[\frac{p}{q}\right]$.

Comment: But what about counterexample that I made. It seems to show at least that $5 \equiv 1 \not \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.And that's why $(-p/q) = -(p/q)$ does not hold universally. Only in special cases.

Comment: How you get that if(Supplement 1)
$x^2 ≡ −1 (mod p)$ is solvable if and only if $p ≡ 1 (mod 4)$, then (-p/q)=-(p/q) exactly when $ q \equiv 3 \pmod 4$?